# How can I solve this problem TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django-templates, python-templates

TEMPLATES = [ { 'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates/calculatorapp')], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {